# Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#<Object>' react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am in the process of updating my react native project to the latest version. I am also using typescript. I am copying a lot of old code into and one code bit is this

```
 let groupSelected = this.props.screenProps.contactGroups[this.state.groupIndexSelected]

 this.setState({
    expandedContacts: [...this.state.expandedContacts, groupSelected],
  })

groupSelected.GroupDropdownMenuChoices.forEach(choice => {
    choice.selected = false
    choice.selectedNotAll = false
})
```

I am getting this error

**Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#'**

Can I get some help here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the array iterative, you can use `map`.

You can just replace the both variables like this:

```js
groupSelected.GroupDropdownMenuChoices.map(choice => ({
    ...choice,
    selected: false,
    selectedNotAll: false,
}));
```